# when form X closes how do I make something happen to form Y

Tags: c#, winforms

When the button is clicked a second form 'uxDGVdatabase' is shown and the controls in the calling form are disabled. When the user closes uxDGVdatabase I'd like the controls in uxRevisionHelperForm to be enabled again.

So I've assumed that I'll need to use a delegate to do this? In uxRevisionHelperForm I have the following:

```
    public delegate void myDelegate(); 

    private void updateDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        myDelegate letsTryThis = new myDelegate(activateGroupBorder);

        uxRevisionHelperGroupBox.Enabled = false;
        uxDGVdatabase myNewDisplay = new uxDGVdatabase();
        myNewDisplay.Show();
    }

    public void activateGroupBorder() {
        uxRevisionHelperGroupBox.Enabled = true;
    }
```

In uxDGVdatabase I have the following - what code needs to go in here?

```
    private void uxDGVdatabase_closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the event handler in the wrong class.  You'll want it like this:

```
    uxRevisionHelperGroupBox.Enabled = false;
    uxDGVdatabase myNewDisplay = new uxDGVdatabase();
    myNewDisplay.FormClosed += delegate { uxRevisionHelperGroupBox.Enabled = true; }
    myNewDisplay.Show();
```

Keep in mind that events are useful to code in *another* class.

Comment: ok ... so object X's events are useful to object Y => I should put the code concerning X's events in Y's class?

Comment: I have no idea what X or Y might be.  But generally, yes.  This is well covered in any introductory book about .NET programming, be sure to pick one up from your local library.

Comment: I've got several introductory books Hans; SO is a great mentoring tool. Thanks for the help.